# Ajax post sending JSON to method resulting null

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, model-view-controller

I can't understand where the issue is.
I have a AJAX call that pass to the controller an object with some file paths to download.
This is the AJAX call:

```
var listD = [];  
listD.push("Some Text");  
listD.push("Some other Text");  
var oList = {};  
oList.Urls=listD;  
                    $.ajax({  
                    method: 'POST',  
                    url: '/api/file/DownloadM/',  
                    data: JSON.stringify(oList),  
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                    success: function (response) {  
                        alert("OOOOOOK");  
                    },  
                    error: function (response) {  
                        alert("NOOOOOOO");  
                }  });
```

I have a model called DownloadUrls in my application:

```
public class DownloadUrl
    {
        string[] Urls { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is my method:

```
    [Route("api/file/downloadM/")]//{username}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadM(DownloadUrl postedData) {
              --do some stuff---
    }
```

I don't understand why my postedData is an object  with Urls property set to null.
If i declare postedData as object i get my JSON text.

What am i missing? I'm quite new in web developing and i'll start to destroy the desk with my head.

Comment: Can you not just pass it a list of strings instead of an object with a list of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not stringify the object you are passing in the data field in the jquery Ajax call.

Try skipping JSON.stringify():

```
$.ajax({  
   method: 'POST',  
   url: '/api/file/DownloadM/',  
   data: oList,  
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
   success: function (response) {  
        alert("OOOOOOK");  
   },  
   error: function (response) {  
        alert("NOOOOOOO");  
   }
});
```

**Edit:** I also notice that the Urls property in your class is not marked as public.  Make sure that it's marked as public so the model binder can populate the property successfully.

```
public class DownloadUrl
{
      public string[] Urls { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it is still null

Comment: Thank you! I had to use JSON.stringify, but the issue was the missing public in the class. :)